# PHP calculation logic issue

Tags: php, math, logic, rounding

Not sure if I'm being stupid here. Probably something obvious but when you've been staring at the same issue for hours on end it starts to drive you crazy.

I'm doing a few calcuations using PHP, all fairly straight forward.

I have a table called sales, say:

```
total, costs
424.53, 125
853.91, 125
```

To get the data I need...

```
gross = total - cost
vat   = gross - ( gross / 1.2 )
profit = gross - vat
```

I need to generate a report, so for each row in the sales database I need to loop over and run the above calculations to get the data I need.

If I add the sum of total and the sum of costs, and then work out the gross, vat and profit above, and round vat and profit to 2 decimal plates the values are as expected.

The problem I'm having is where I'm looping over each row and calculating gross, vat and profit. If I don't round vat and profit on each row, but round the final totals, they match the values where I add `sum(total)` and `sum(costs)`.

But then in the report I generate, if I don't round vat and profit then they don't show to two decimal places, which I need.

Actual code is below, pretty sure it's more of a logic issue than code.

```
    $sum = 0; // Test variable
    foreach( .. as ... )
    {
        // Assigning $total and $cost

        $gross = $total - $cost;

        $data['profit'] = $gross;

        // If I round this VAT so vat shows to two decimal points, $sum becomes off by some pence.
        // If I don't round it but then round $sum after the loop, it matches the echo statement value which is the correct amount
        $vat = $this->vat( $gross );

        $data['vat'] = $vat;

        $profit = $gross - $vat;

        $data['net_profit'] = $profit;

        $sum += $profit;

        $array[] = $data;
    }

    echo "131547.82<br><br>";

    echo $sum;
    die;
```

Comment: I would suggest NOT using the default php float for currency or accounting for the reasons outlined here. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php What you want to do is use a currency object. There are a few if you just google them. Otherwise you are going to end up with some whacky stuff occasionally.

Comment: Looks like you're having a simple rounding error, e.g. `0.3561 + 0.1283 + 2.2193 + 1.1459 + 7.1389` gives 10.9885 which rounds to 10.99, but if you round each, `0.36 + 0.13 + 2.22 + 1.15 + 7.14` gives 11.00. When the differences between the rounded values and the actual ones accumulate to more than 0.01, you'll have a mismatch, and that's expected.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was pretty sure that was the issue but just wanted to confirm. If I format cells in the csv report generated to 2 decimal places, that seems to do the trick as it'll still use the unrounded values when doing =SUM().

Comment: It's actually a common problem, see e.g. https://adminimize.nl/en/news/4/automatic-book-mismatch-due-to-vat-rounding-differences or https://www.drupal.org/node/1137840

Comment: @PedroGimeno Your comments answer the question, you should post them as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's an accuracy problem caused by using floats.

When you do calculations with pure PHP you need to be careful.
You may run into glitches, when comparing two floats.
I would suggest to use some helper function or a currency / money object in order to work with them. It might be better to use a PHP Extension for math stuff, like the PHP Extensions BCMath, which has for instance the function [bcadd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php). Anyway, here are some helpers, which you might use in your calculation loop.

```
/**
 * turn "string float" into "rounded float with precision 2"
 * (string) 123,19124124 = (float) 123.19
 * 
 * @param type $string
 */
function formatNumber($string, $precision = 2)
{
    return round((float) str_replace(',', '.', $string), $precision);
}
```

There is also [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php): `echo sprintf("%.2f", $a);`.

These two are based on PHP's [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/de/class.numberformatter.php) from the Intl Extension.

```
// 123,19 EUR = 123.19
function parseNumber($string_number)
{
    $fmt = numfmt_create('de_DE', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    return numfmt_parse($fmt, $string_number);
}

// 123.19 = 123,19 EUR
function numberFormat($value)
{
    $f = \NumberFormatter::create("de_DE", \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    return $f->formatCurrency($value, 'EUR');
}
```

For comparing two floats:

```
/** 
 * Do not check, that the numbers are exactly the same, 
 * but check that their difference is very small!
 * A really small rounding error margin (epsilon) is expected.
 * It's an equals check within defined precision.
 */
function compareFloats($a, $b)
{
    return (abs(($a - $b) / $b) < 0.000001) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: The issue here is not float precision. The very same will happen with BCmath if the numbers are truncated or rounded, no matter the precision. See my first comment to the OP.

Comment: It is an accuracy problem caused by using floats. I have adressed both issues: precision and rounding. The NumberFormatter is helpful for these kind of issues. anyway, thanks for the downvote

Comment: The mismatch is a consequence of rounding the VAT to two decimal places. No representation whatsoever will deal with that problem.

Comment: Scroll to the end of this post http://www.stichlberger.com/software/java-bigdecimal-gotchas/ to the section titled "General rounding topics in monetary calculations" to see why it wouldn't help. That page is about a Java type which has the same numeric precision as the BC math module. It mentions the correct solution there: to tweak the intermediate values so that the final result matches. It's not that float accuracy can't bite you, as noted in the same post, but that's not what's happening here.